# Código só funciona quando reinicia o PC

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, xampp

Estou criando uma aplicação na sua maioria em PHP, e ocorreu algumas vezes ao fazer uma chamada em Java, JQuery ou CSS e as vezes até mesmo outra página em PHP e não funciona como deveria.

Percorri o código e estava tudo ok. Então reinicio o PC uma ou duas vezes e o código funciona perfeitamente.

Alguém sabe o motivo disso ?

Comment: Consegue demonstrar o código ?
Algumas vezes o JavaScript , CSS e afins que são Front-End fica salvo no cache do navegador.

Comment: Não consigo demonstrar o código agora, mais pelo que pesquisei é isso mesmo.
As vezes faço alguma alteração no código, mais o navegador busca pelo cache e acaba dando erro.

Comment: Você não está pegando algum valor vindo de sessão?  não precisa reiniciar o pc, apenas o servido no xampp.

Comment: Não estou pegando nenhum valor de sessão.
Da próxima vez vou tentar reiniciar somente o XAMPP.
É bem mais prático.

Answer (score 2):

Já aconteceu comigo algo semelhante, estava desenvolve uma página web para meu TCC todo em Javascript, ao publicar para teste, percebi que havia um erro, corrigi o mesmo e atualizei a página e nada... Nem reiniciando. Então falei pros meus amigos testarem no computadores dele e estava sem o erro.

Então, é muito provável que o seu erro, na verdade, seja um 'erro' no navegador que esta salvando o JavaScript e CSS no Cache.

Soluções Prováveis:
1) Reiniciar apenas o servidor
2) Limpar o cache do navegador (mais recomendado)
3) Usar guia anônima